# Android AlertDialog highlight on default value?

Tags: android

Say you have a

```
public class PickerFragment extends DialogFragment { 
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
         //.....
         return builder.create();
}
```

I have the default value set to 1, how can I highlight it so that someone who opens it will see item 1 selected? Thanks in advance.